# click jquery button + send data without form - bookmark

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm working on a bookmarking function where the user clicks on a jQueryui button and certain information is sent to the database. But I'm not using a form, because there is no information for the user to enter.

I'm pulling the user's ID from the session data, and I'm sending a URI segment (portion of the URL)

Using codeigniter/php.

I'm trying to figure out what to put in the data portion of the ajax/post function, since there's no form/no data entered, and what to do about the "submit" part of the controller.

**Controller**

```
function addBookmark(){

        if ($this->input->post('submit')) {

            $id = $this->session->userdata('id');               
            $bookmark = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);

            $this->bookmarks_model->postBookmark($id, $bookmark);
        }

    }
```

**Model**

```
function postBookmark() {

     $data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'bookmark_id' => $bookmark,
    );

    $this->db->insert('bookmarks', $data);

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="somebutton">Add bookmark</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.somebutton').click(function() { 

            $.ajax({
                url: 'controller/addBookmark',
                type: 'POST',
                data: ???,
                success: function (result) {
                  alert("Your bookmark has been saved");
                }
            });  

    });
```

Comment: @wallyk The model (bookmarks_model) is connected to the controller by the last line of the controller function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is you are checking for a `submit` key in the `POST` args. You can either fake it by sending `data: {submit:true}` or by by removing your if statement and just processing a POST request

```
$('.somebutton').click(function() { 

        $.ajax({
            url: 'controller/addBookmark',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'submit':true}, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;
            success: function (result) {
              alert("Your bookmark has been saved");
            }
        });  

});
```

Comment: I tried this with data: {submit:true} and without data. I also tried it without the if function. I'm getting the alert, but nothing is being added to the database.

Comment: Okay, I did some maneuvering with my buttons and it is now working--with nothing in the data field as you suggested. Instead, I added a hidden field to get the data to pass. I've accepted and upvoted your answer, since it was the closest. (Now if I can just get the alert to work!) :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.ajax()` use either [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Using `.get()`

```
 $.get('controller/addBookmark',function(data){ 
     alert('Your bookmark has been saved'); 
 });
```

Using `.post()`

```
 $.post('controller/addBookmark', function(data) {
     alert('Your bookmark has been saved, The contents of the page were:' + data); 
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try now. What should be in the "data" place? Just the word data?

Comment: `data` is the results of the page on the callback.

Comment: Okay; how do I indicate data in the function? I don't have any inputs

Comment: The `data` variable is an output of the contents of the submitted page, in case you want to return it in your code , not an input.. See the example of how it's used under the `.post()` example.

Comment: Okay, I tried both functions. The first produced an alert, but nothing is in the database. The second gave me an alert, but it contained an exception error; also nothing in the database. Any other thoughts? I'm really stumped with this.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know PHP, so it's something in your PHP code that isn't setup properly..  This simply sends a request to the page with no further post data, as your question states.  If you were saying the 2nd one gave you an error, then that means your php page is returning an error and the `data` variable is catching it from the php page and putting it into the alert box.  You may need to debug your `controller/addBookmark` page.

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation of [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.

If you do not know what to put for the data, probably you should remove that option? In your controller function addBookmark(), you can reduce the code by remove the if check. Try this and see if it works for you.

Comment: @chowwy check your code `$this->bookmarks_model->postBookmark($id, $bookmark);` in your controller and `function postBookmark() {` in your model, is the call made correctly?

Comment: The variable `$user_id` and `$bookmark` in function is a local variable to function `postBookmark()`. The function `addBookmark()` call `bookmarks_model->postBookmark($id, $bookmark);` with **two** parameters. So you are passing two parameters to function postBookmark but in the function `postBookmark`, it expect no parameter. So really, how is the insertion into database is done?

Comment: That was just an oversight when I transferred the code. I have the function working fine without jQuery. But I'd like to post the information to the database using an ajax/post function.