# How to send ajax request in rails app without using remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, erb

This is working just fine

```
<%#= link_to t('.add_html'), 'javascript:void(0);', :class => "line-item", :product => product.id %>

$('document').ready(function(){
        $(".line-item").click(function(){
            var prod = $(this).attr('product');
            $.ajax({
                url:'<%#= line_items_url %>',
                data: {product_id: prod},
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'script'
            });
        });
    });
```

But when I use button nothing happens. Please let me know what am I missing here?

```
<%= button_to t('.add_html'), 'javascript:void(0);', :class => "line-item", :product => product.id %>
```

Comment: You sure you have JQuery running & added to your pages?

Comment: Use proper button id and proper ajax calling with jquery

[Like here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406571/click-jquery-button-send-data-without-form-bookmark

Answer (score 0):

`:remote => :true` just creates an ajax request; you can do your own ajax request no problem:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href");
        success: function(data) { //handle returned data },
        error: function(data)   { //handle errors }
    });
});
```

I think you are asking a different question (how to get your call working), which I can update the answer to reflect if you wish

Comment: should I use href in the attr("href"); or I should use the link there?

Comment: You can use link! Only problem is I don't think your syntax is correct; but you literally just put your link in there. How you get it is irrelevant

Comment: It is working fine for link but not working for button. Please check the question now

Comment: Okay, you have to remember that [`button_to` basically creates a form](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to), so you'd have to do something like `url: $(this).parent().attr("action");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent default:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(ev){
        $.post(this.url); // I'm not sure this is correct
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: It is working fine for link but not working for button. Please check the question now

Comment: Why do you have to use the button_to helper?
 <button type="button" class="line-item" product="#{product.id}"><%= t('.add_html') %></button>